# Sitecore FXM issue - parent selector is missing in Add to Placeholder dialog

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to use Federated Experience Manager with an external website. The static website has a JS beacon, so now I am able to open external page with Experience Editor.

The issue happens when I try to add a placeholder to that external static page (as per guide), parent dropbox do not present, so I am not able to create a placeholder and any other operations FXM allows.

[image]

Is that a bug of Sitecore? I am on 8.0 Update 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had that issue in past when tried to investigate Sitecore 8 new features. I know it may sound weird, but this happens because your license does not have FMX in it.

If you got you your license.xml file from previous sitecore versions, then FXM would not be there, you need to request new license from Sitecore that has this feature enabled.

**Update:** The good way to test that is to look beacon file content (ex. in dev. tools) - if you do no have license beacon would just have missing license text without any actual content. You may check what you are actually licensed for from Sitecore menu (or hamburger menu in 8.0+) from Content Editor, then selecting Licenses. If you do not see something like Sitecore.Federated Experience (or similar by sense) then you are definitely out of license for FXM.

Also, it is mentioned in the official Requirements and Limitations article: https://goo.gl/wZfEhQ

Comment: Just checked beacon script file and it says missing license indeed. Sad news for us then, need to update license...